# Script encrypting Mails on Server [Maildir/GPG]

Tags: encryption, email-server, maildir

The idea is to encrypt [cronjob] all mails older than x days with a certain [per user] PGP Key.
Mails are stored in Maildir format.

Are you guys aware of an existing solution to this?
Or maybe someone's got a script lying around that does a similar thing, so I don't have to start from scratch.. ;)

Thanks

Comment: Do you just need the mails encrypted, or do you need them encrypted such that the users' mail clients can still decrypt the individual messages?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but here's info on how to encrypt all incoming email with GPG

http://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/mailserver